# Automatic initialization routine in C++ library?

Tags: c++, initialization

If i have a header file foo.h and a source file foo.cpp, and foo.cpp contains something along the lines of:

```
#ifdef WIN32
class asdf {
   asdf() { startup_code(); }
   ~asdf() { cleanup_code(); }
};
asdf __STARTUP_HANDLE__
#else
//unix does not require startup or cleanup code in this case
#endif
```

but foo.h does not define class asdf, say i have an application bar.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"
//link in foo.lib, foo.dll, foo.so, etc
int main() {
   //do stuff
   return 0;
}
```

If bar.cpp is compiled on a WIN32 platform, will the asdf() and ~asdf() be called at the appropriate times (before main() and at program exit, respectively) even though class asdf is not defined in foo.h, but is linked in through foo.cpp?

Comment: You're not seriously naming the object `__STARTUP_HANDLE__`, right? All names containing a double underscore *or* beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved to the implementation. The name could conflict with some compiler #define or object defined by the runtime. Never *ever* use names like that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes -- but be very careful. The order in which static objects (like your `asdf` object) are initialized is undefined. So it is undefined behavior if any other object tries to reference your object before `main()`.

Also, `__STARTUP_HANDLE__` is not a valid identifier. Double-underscores are not allowed in any identifier (even macros), and a single-underscore followed by a capital letter is also not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it. Look out for the static initialization order issue, as the other answers say. But you really should fix that reserved identifier.

`__STARTUP_HANDLE__` does work similar to a runtime library, and runtime libraries use names like that, but it's not part of the runtime library so that name isn't allowed.

```
#ifdef WIN32
namespace { // anonymous namespace - no outside access
class asdf {
   asdf() { startup_code(); }
   ~asdf() { cleanup_code(); }
} x; // to create an instance
}
```

Comment: Why don't you need to name the class?  Doesn't the compiler need to have an identifier for the type such that it can decide the name of the constructor/destructor?

Comment: @Robert: sorry, that was stupid before. Yes, the class needs to have a name to have a constructor :vP

Answer (score 0):

As long as the objects (foo.o) themselves are linked into the executable, this will work (assuming the static initialization order fiasco doesn't hit you).  If you're pulling it in from a library (foo.lib), though, it won't unless you explicitly mark the object as an "active object," but I don't remember how to do that in MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows and with DLL's you have the possibility to use the function [`DllMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583(VS.85).aspx) that will be called at load etc

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
                    DWORD fdwReason,
                    LPVOID lpvReserved) {  

  switch (fdwReason) {

  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:    
    break;

  case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    break;

  case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    break;

  case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;

  default:
    break;
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: To complement this, on Linux you can tag plain *functions* that take no arguments as having the `constructor` or `destructor` attribute. The linker then arranges for them to be called at program start/library load (or exit/unload) as part of the mechanism that supports C++ objects with those lifetimes.